# In PostgreSQL, is it possible to have a default format for real columns?

Tags: postgresql, floating-point, formatting

In PostgreSQL, I have a column with people's height in meters. If the height is, say 1.75 m, it shows properly, but if the height is 1.70 m, it shows as 1.7. I would like to have this already formatted to two decimal places, showing as 1.70 **without formatting in each and every SQL call**. Can I specify this in the table creation? Or a stored procedure, or something? I've seen a few things about timestamps, but not for real fields. Knowing how to format the decimal point as a colon (1,70) would be a plus.

Comment: Hello, as is I don't think you can. One way to do this would be to create a view with formatted values. Does that help?

Comment: @g_bor Yes, see the comment on the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, presentation and "cosmetics" are the job of the application, not the database.

Having a default number of decimal places for floats would also create a problem, because the data returned by the database would not be the actual data in the column. So if you did a SELECT and it returned a value of 1.75, then if you searched for this value, you might not find it because the actual value stored was not 1.75 but 1.7499999999 and it was only rounded for display.

Potential solutions:

- If you want to store a specified number of digits, use NUMERIC. This will solve the 1.7499999999 problem above. If you use NUMERIC, when doing a SELECT you get the actual contents of the column.
- In your app, if you use an ORM, use a Decimal (or similar) type for the column with the appropriate settings so it displays the way you want.
- Or create a view with the format applied to the column, but in this case if you want the trailing zero, the type will be text and not float, and it will not be searchable unless you create an extra index on it.
- [Generated column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html) with the number formatted as you want, maybe easier than a view

Comment: I'm not searching by this field, only comparing and filtering, and this already leads me to floating-point approximation issues (already solved). I'm using real because its calculations are faster than numeric. I don't use ORM. Tried with the view, but since some rows are formatted differently (according to other column), I need an UNION on the view definition, which makes it not updatable :( Still, it seems the best solution so far. Thank you!

Comment: You could also use a generated column, if you don't mind wasting the space...